# Open always a predefined folder at start in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Maybe this sounds easy but I would like to know if is possible to open always a "default" folder when VS Code starts.

Actually VSCode open the last folder opened, but I want open always the same predefined folder.

For example, if I open VS-Code, it starts at a folder called `FolderA`. Now, if I open a new folder doing `File > Open Folder > FolderB` and then close VSCode and start again, the folder at init is "FolderB".

So, I want create a "default folder" and every time I open VSCode, it starts at "FolderA".

If I open `FolderB` and I close VSCode, when the program reruns, I would like to see `FolderA` always.

I've only found questions from a couple years ago with no much information about it. Some of them saying it is not possible.

Comment: How are you opening vscode?  And are these folders part of a workspace?

Comment: Hi, @Mark, I open vscode clicking the shortcout. And the folders are not part of a workspace, they are only folders with files.